# ObjC / iOS - Capitalize first letters of each word without modifying other letters

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there an easy way to transform a string "**dino mcCool**" to a string "**Dino McCool**"?

using the '`capitalizedString`' method I would just get `@"Dino Mccool"`

Comment: add a space between mc and cool

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can enumerate the words of the string and modify each word separately.
This works even if the words are separated by other characters than a space character:

```
NSString *str = @"dino mcCool. foo-bAR";
NSMutableString *result = [str mutableCopy];
[result enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [result length])
                           options:NSStringEnumerationByWords
                        usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
        [result replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(substringRange.location, 1)
                              withString:[[substring substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];
}];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
// Output: Dino McCool. Foo-BAR
```

Comment: I did not know NSStringEnumerationByWords but is it localized ?

Comment: @tdelepine: There is an NSStringEnumerationLocalized option which you can add: *"Causes the enumeration to occur using user's default locale. This does not make a difference in line, paragraph, or composed character sequence enumeration, but it may for words or sentences."*

Comment: Thanks buddy you help me to implement exact functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
- (NSString *)capitilizeEachWord:(NSString *)sentence {
    NSArray *words = [sentence componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSMutableArray *newWords = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *word in words) {
        if (word.length > 0) {
            NSString *capitilizedWord = [[[word substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString] stringByAppendingString:[word substringFromIndex:1]];
            [newWords addObject:capitilizedWord];
        }
    }
    return [newWords componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
}
```

Comment: Just note that multiple spaces are collapsed to a single space.

Comment: @MartinR, is it problem?

Comment: It was just a remark, because `capitalizedString` preserves all spaces.

Comment: Perfect.  In my case I needed to convert `someTableName` to `SomeTableName` and this avoids the flaw in `capitalizedString` which would give me `Sometablename`