# NSString: capitalize, but preserve uppercase in non-leading characters

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I would like to capitalize NSStrings. This class has a convenience method so you can e.g.:

```
[@"hello" capitalizedString]; // "Hello"
```

however, this will lowercase any non-leading characters in the string e.g.:

```
[@"hello WORLD" capitalizedString]; // "Hello World"
```

for the second example, the output I need is `"Hello WORLD"`

Is there something which does that for me, or does it need to be rolled by hand? thanks!

Comment: Your may check here .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520434/objc-ios-capitalize-first-letters-of-each-word-without-modifying-other-lette

Comment: that works, thanks!